# continuous overlapping paths in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, overlay

I'm attempting to re-create a SVG version of the Alfresco logo viewed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Alfresco-logo.png

The problem that I'm running into with [my .svg](http://scottymiller.net/alfresco.svg) is that when I create the 8 paths (3 blue fill, 4 green fill, one orange fill), I am unsuccessful at positioning the various paths to create a continuous consistent overlap for all paths.  I always end up with one path that is out of place and either sits on top of both adjacent paths, or behind, creating an inconsistent pattern.  What is the best way in Inkscape to create this consistent overlapping pattern of 8 paths so that one is not left out as the odd one in the pattern?  Is there a way to split one of the paths so that one half is set beneath one adjacent path and overlaps the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a larger version picked randomly from google search: ( http://jamesonbull.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/alfresco_logo.jpg )

I see a few minor differences: your white outline is transparent; your final orange overlay is not orange and yellow...

However, if you conceive of the repeating element as this:

[image: chunk]

Your problem no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

Horatio is absolutely right - the symbol is made up of rotated cutout sections, not complete 'petals'.

The method consists of creating one petal, rotating it 45% and then subtracting one shape from the other using the path difference and intersection tools.

The SVG (from InkScape v0.48) for the image below can be **[found here](http://www.thinkui.co.uk/examples/alfresco.svg)** and can be used on black or white. Feel free to use this and recolour for your own needs - I have left each area of colour individually changeable.

I accept no responsibility if you use it unchanged for your own business logo... :-)

[image]

Comment: I very much appreciate the effort you've gone through designing the graphic.  Well done!